# SQLServer Campo Identity pula para 1001

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Notei que uma das tabelas teve um saldo do 9 para 1001. A princípio imaginei que algum colega teria feito um teste no banco e excluído o registro na sequencia fazendo com que o número tivesse esse salto.

Agora aconteceu com uma outra tabela sem que ninguém tenha feito um insert com posterior exclusão. Alguém já teve esse problema? Essa é a tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PcpsRota](
    [RotaId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmpId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RotaDes] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [UsuId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UsuDta] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UltUsuId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UltDta] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [RotaSit] [smallint] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RotaId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PcpsRota] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [UltDta]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PcpsRota] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RotaSit]  DEFAULT ((2)) FOR [RotaSit]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PcpsRota]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CHK_PcpsRota_UltimoUsuario_DeveSerInformado] CHECK  (([UltUsuId]>(0)))
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PcpsRota] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CHK_PcpsRota_UltimoUsuario_DeveSerInformado]
GO
```

Comment: Cara, eu li um caso, que parece muito com o seu. Só que é relacionado ao postgres, mas talvez lendo sobre este caso possa te explicar o motivo: [artigo](https://incident.io/blog/one-two-skip-a-few). Neste caso eles resolveram deixando de utilizar sequências geradas pelo banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

A partir da versão SQL Server 2012, por motivos de performance, os valores `IDENTITY` são armazenados em cache e alguns desses valores podem ser perdidos durante uma falha no banco de dados ou quando o servidor reinicia, assim resultando em um gap na sequência dos valores. Esse é o comportamento padrão do SQL Server.

Se você não deseja esse comportamento, você tem duas opções:

1. Usar uma `SEQUENCE` com a opção `NOCACHE`.

   ```
    CREATE SEQUENCE CountBy1
        START WITH 1
        INCREMENT BY 1
        NOCACHE;
    GO

    CREATE TABLE t1 (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR CountBy1, 
    col INT NOT NULL);
    GO
   ```
2. Ou, usar a trace flag 272.

Microsoft Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms186775(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN